# Open Shift Mysql data connection using php

Tags: php, mysqli, openshift

I am fresher for Open shift.
Here is my problem in Open shift.
I completed creating application with php, Mysql and PhpMyAdmin
Then I went to phpMyAdmin and created a new database 'Students_list'
Now I am unable to connect to my database with the following code in php pages.

```
$db_host = $_ENV['127.12.123.2']; //sample host 
$db_user = $_ENV['adminnxUpXA6'];
$db_pass = $_ENV['lyPfbtHYpDFcU'];
$db_name = $_ENV['students_list']; //this is the database I created in PhpMyAdmin

$db = new mysqli($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass);

if ($db->connect_errno) {

    die('Connect Error (' . $db->connect_errno . ') '
        . $db->connect_error);
}
mysqli_select_db($db,$db_name);
```

May I please know where I am comitting the error.

Comment: Please don't post your credentials.

Comment: The actual error might be helpful

Comment: Do you really have an array called `$_ENV` with the indizes you use above?

Comment: You need to change your credentials.  You just posted them to a public website, and there's no way to remove them from the Internet now (Google has them in its cache).

Answer (score 3):

Try this instead:

```
$db_host = getenv('OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST'); //sample host 
$db_user = getenv('OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_USERNAME');
$db_pass = getenv('OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PASSWORD');
$db_name = 'students_list'; //this is the database I created in PhpMyAdmin

$db = new mysqli($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass);

if ($db->connect_errno) {

    die('Connect Error (' . $db->connect_errno . ') '
        . $db->connect_error);
}
mysqli_select_db($db,$db_name);
```

Comment: Thank you all, The credentials i added are not real. I manipulated before posting them. Very happy for the Answers. I shall check and get Back. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `$_ENV`, which contains environment variables from the operating system. Most probably what you wanted to do is this:

```
$db_host = 'ip';
$db_user = 'username';
$db_pass = 'password';
$db_name = 'students_list';
```

Answer (score 0):

The structure for the mysqli connection string is this:

```
mysqli(Hostname,Username,Password,DatabaseName);
```